# jQuery UI - I want to check if a resize event was triggered on a resizable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

I have two divs $('.list') and $('.content') side by side. $('.list') is resizable using jQuery UI resizable and $('.content') is bound to the alsoResize.

The problem I am having is I need to know when the resizable event is triggered.  .bind('change') or .bind('resize') don't work because resize is only for the window/frame and 'change' seems to be an IE only event.

The solution I had in mind was to actively 'watch' for any changes to the width of the $('.list') div and trigger an event but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

What I can't do is put this inside the resize event because it has to live inside an independent jQuery plugin.  I want the jQuery plugin to watch for any changes.

Thanks!

Comment: The same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507902/resetting-element-css-attributes-on-container-resize-event-onresize/8560374#8560374 You can find an answer there

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure but did you try this. I found it in the documentations in the jquery ui website:

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({     resize: function(event, ui) { ... }   });
```